# AWS download file to iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/temp.txt", documentPath];
NSLog(temp);




// create our stream
NSOutputStream *outputStream =
[[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:temp append:YES];
[outputStream open];

// create our request
S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest =
[[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:self.objectName
withBucket:self.bucket];
getObjectRequest.outputStream = outputStream;




// always make sure to close your streams when done
[outputStream close];
```

Comment: Where do you want it to go?

Comment: Doesn't really matter I just want to be able to view the file for verification that the transfer was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` to get the documents directory for your application and use it to build the file path and name.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Ok so I save the stream to documentPath, but how am I able to view that file..I.E. open the Document Directory?

Comment: It depends on the contents of the file.  The short answer is you can load the file into an NSData buffer and then do something with it.  The following code loads the file specified by filePath and then displays it in a UIWebView, which could be used to show the file contents if they were HTML.  `NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; [self.webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];`